Help Needed: Deployment Issues with Aave V2 Flash Loan Contract on Avalanche Fuji Testnet
I'm encountering persistent issues while deploying a flash loan smart contract using Aave V2 on the Avalanche Fuji Testnet. Despite multiple attempts, I'm receiving errors indicating that the transaction reverts due to calling a non-contract account. Here are the details and steps I've taken:
Project Information:
Framework: Hardhat
Blockchain Network: Avalanche Fuji Testnet
Smart Contract Language: Solidity 0.6.12

Dependencies:
@aave/protocol-v2   
@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle
@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers
ethers
@openzeppelin/contracts
ethereum-waffle

 Error: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
This error occurs consistently, indicating that a function call is being made to an address that isn't recognized as a contract.
Steps Taken:
Checked Contract Addresses:
Used PoolAddressesProvider for Aave V2 on Fuji Testnet.
const providerAddress = "0x7fdC1FdF79BE3309bf82f4abdAD9f111A6590C0f"; // PoolAddressesProvider for Aave V2

Diagnostic Script with Additional Logging:
Implemented to check if addresses are indeed contracts.
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const providerAddress = "0x7fdC1FdF79BE3309bf82f4abdAD9f111A6590C0f";
  console.log("Checking PoolAddressesProvider address:", providerAddress);

  const code = await ethers.provider.getCode(providerAddress);
  console.log("PoolAddressesProvider code:", code);
  if (code === '0x') {
    console.error("Error: PoolAddressesProvider address is not a contract.");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const FlashLoan = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyFlashLoanContract");
  const flashLoan = await FlashLoan.deploy(providerAddress);

  await flashLoan.deployed();
  console.log("Contract deployed at:", flashLoan.address);

  const wbtcAddress = "0xYourFujiWBTCAddress";
  console.log("Checking WBTC address:", wbtcAddress);

  const codeWBTC = await ethers.provider.getCode(wbtcAddress);
  console.log("WBTC contract code:", codeWBTC);
  if (codeWBTC === '0x') {
    console.error("Error: WBTC address is not a contract.");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const lendingPoolAddress = await flashLoan._addressesProvider.getLendingPool();
  console.log("Checking Lending Pool address:", lendingPoolAddress);

  const codeLendingPool = await ethers.provider.getCode(lendingPoolAddress);
  console.log("Lending Pool contract code:", codeLendingPool);
  if (codeLendingPool === '0x') {
    console.error("Error: Lending Pool address is not a contract.");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  try {
    console.log("Attempting to approve infinite allowance...");
    const tx1 = await flashLoan.approveInfinite(wbtcAddress, {
      gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from("10000000")
    });
    await tx1.wait();
    console.log("Infinite approval granted!");

    console.log("Attempting flash loan...");
    const tx2 = await flashLoan.flashLoan(wbtcAddress, ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.01", 8), {
      gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from("10000000")
    });
    await tx2.wait();
    console.log("Flash loan executed!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Deployment script completed successfully.");
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Deployment error:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

Configuration File:
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.6.12",
      }
    ]
  },
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
      gas: 10000000,
      gasPrice: 20000000000
    },
    fuji: {
      url: "https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc",
      accounts: ["0xYourPrivateKey"], // замени на свой приватный ключ
      gas: 10000000,
      gasPrice: 25000000000,
      chainId: 43113
    }
  }
};

Could you please help me identify what might be causing these issues, particularly

Hi! When you run the script that you detailed above (to check if the addresses you're using are indeed contracts), what is the result?
